# How do I select all documents manager

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I'm new to Lotus development and I need to create a view that shows where the user is manager of another database besides its own mail.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The Domain Catalog does this for you.  A Notes Administrator can turn on the service that catalogs all of your environment's databases.  Within the Domino Directory, go to the Server Document and click on the Server Tasks tab.  Within that tab you'll find the Domain Catalog tab which lets you enable the service.

After the service runs, you'll be able to view the Domain Catalog database, usually stored as catalog.nsf.  That database will include the access control lists for all the databases and let you sort/group by access level.  You can always create a custom view if it doesn't show the lists exactly as you need them, but you'll likely find the default views are good enough.

Note, I'm using Domino 6.x so things may/probably have changed in more recent versions, however the gist is the same.

Comment: Yes I have reviewed the catalog.nsf and actually the view named "By Name" under "Access Control Lists" folder have the information I need, but I want to filter out the users that are managers of only its own DB

Comment: Categorise the view by name then restrict the view to display the category for the relevant user.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Ken's idea of using the Domain Catalog. You can create your own view in there, (providing you have permission from the administrators). Make a copy the "Access Control Lists\By Name" view, and call it "Access Control List\Manager by Name" and change the view formula to read as:

SELECT @IsAvailable(ReplicaID)& @IsUnavailable(RepositoryType)& !(DBListInCatalog = "0") & @trim(ManagerList) !=""

This should include all those entries for people who have manager access.